# Table Sorter to sort when i have more rows in thead

Tags: tablesorter

I have a table with more than 2 rows in  and i wnt to perform sorting only on 2nd row elements, how can this be achieved using table sorter?Please help me out.

Comment: what programming language are you using?!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but I only use the first row for tablesorter. The second row is used for selection filters, so I always want it to stay at row 2. Putting both rows in  but making the second row  cells instead of `<th>` cells does the trick.

```
<table id="table" class="tablesorter">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th title="Click to sort by ID ">ID</th>
         <th title="Click to sort by Name ">Name</th>
         <th title="Click to sort by Description ">Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="org_id"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="business_desc"/></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Org 1</td>
         <td>Org Name</td>
         <td>Org Desc</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

BY default it will take your last .

for changing it to first you can use.
var table = $('#stu_view_example1 ').DataTable({
         orderCellsTop: true
or
         "bSortCellsTop": true
    });