# Fill HTML table by reading an excel sheet using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have a html table as below. This table only has table headings.

```
<table id="table-0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to fill this html table with data using javascript/jQuery. Table data should be come from an excel sheet. i.e. I want to read an excel sheet and fill my html table with those data.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: may be duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6045717/4944490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax fill html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045506/jquery-ajax-fill-html-table)

Comment: this might be a useful resource for you: [parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)